# Implementing interface with methods that take and return type interface

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, types, interface

I've run into a problem. I have to implement this interface:

```
public interface Set_of_objects {
    boolean equal(Set_of_objects s);
    Set_of_objects cross(Set_of_objects s);
}
```

The class implementing it has to take an array of objects and test it with another array of objects. The method "equal" should return true if they are equal (false if they are not equal), and the method "cross" has to return an array of objects consisting of objects that they share.

I haven't been able to figure out how to even compare those 2 arrays because of the type of argument required in the method.

```
public class Object_array_test implements Set_of_objects {
    Object[] x = new Object[5];

    public Object_array_test (Object[] x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public boolean equal(Set_of_objects s) {
        return  s.equals(x);
    }
    public cross(Set_of_objects s) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I do it like this it says:
"Unlikely argument type for equals(): Object[] seems to be unrelated to Set_of_objects"

And when I try casting (like I saw on the internet):

```
Object[] y = (Object[]) s;
```

I get this:

> Cannot cast from Set_of_objects to Object[]

How do I fix this problem and can somebody please explain how does it exactly work?

Comment: Not only is it an unlikely parameter, you should avoid it. I see that your method is called equal, not equals, but still. You may think that this method would replace equals calls through your code, but in most cases, for example when sorting a list, it won't, because it will be (trying to) use the overridden version of equals(Object o), which you don't have, hence, it will use the original

Comment: Stop using underscroes in class names. The Java naming conventions says that you have to use camel case

Comment: The task says that I should implement that interface, I cannot change it. I normally don't put underscored in class names.. I just renamed everything from my language to English

Comment: You can implement an interface without passing the interface type as the argument to compare. What if you compare arrays of the Integer type? You will not be able to type cast those to your type. So you can implement the interface, but are you 100% sure you should implement it as this specific "type"?

Answer (score 0):

A. Just try to read your requirements over again (and slowly :-) ):

> 1. The class implementing it has to take an **array** of objects
> 2. method "cross" has to return an **array** of objects

so... neither

```
boolean equal(Set_of_objects s);
```

nor

```
Set_of_objects cross(Set_of_objects s);
```

satisfy your requirements - `Set_of_objects` is not an **array**, but just an object implemented `Set_of_objects` interface.

your interface's method signatures must look like

```
public interface Set_of_objects {
   boolean equal(Set_of_objects[] s);
   Set_of_objects[] cross(Set_of_objects[] s);
}
```

B. From other hands you can use your `Set_of_objects` as a holder for array as you do... but you need another method (getter for your array e.g. `getX()` ) and use it to compare array members...

P.S. I guess you will figure out how to loop through array to compare Objects and put them into another one to return from `cross` method.

also, in real world it is not recommended  to return new instance of array from methods... but as exercise it does not matter too much.

Good luck!

Comment: I will use it as a holder, I might have made a mistake with that second requirement. THANK YOU! :D

Comment: OK as I understand now: If you cannot change interface it means 1. for equal method you need to loop through both `this` and `s` Object holders `x` and check all members from `this.x` and `s.x` to be equal. for `cross` you need to do almost the same,but put crossing objects into `new Set_of_objects`  `x` holder and then return that new `Set_of_objects` object.

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be a few minor issues here. Here is an updated interface:

```
package com.simi.practice.work.PracticeWork;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;


public interface Set_of_objects {

        boolean equals(Object[] x, Object[] y);

        Object cross(Object[] x, Object[] y);

        }
```

In your original interface you were not passing an Array as an object. You were simply passing an interface "type". You have to pass an actual Array Object however in order to pass an Array to any of your methods or constructors in your class. We can pass an x object and a y object in the interface, and any class implementing the interface will obviously use these methods:

```
package com.simi.practice.work.PracticeWork;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Object_array_test implements Set_of_objects{


    public boolean equals(Object[]s, Object[]t) {
        String v = Arrays.toString(s);
        String r = Arrays.toString(t);

        if(v.equals(r)) {

          return true;
         }

         return false;

      }
    public Object[] cross(Object[]s, Object[]t) {
        ArrayList<Object> n = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for(int x= 0; x<s.length; x++) {
           if(s[x].equals(t[x])) {
              n.add(s[x]);

           }
        }System.out.println(n.toArray());
        Object[] p = n.toArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p));
        return  p;
    }

 }
```

In the code above, you don't know which kind of object you will pass which is why we convert it to a String. As I noted earlier, the methods need to take an Object as an argument in order to work with the Arrays. Simply passing the interface "type" will not work. In the .equals() method we can then compare the two Arrays to see if they are identical. if not, the code will return false. If they are identical, the code will return true.

And lastly, lets test the class and the output:

```
public class App {
        public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, MyException{

        Object_array_test test = new Object_array_test();
        Object[] i = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        Object[] j = {1, 2, 90, 4};
        System.out.println(test.equals(j, i));
        System.out.println(test.cross(i,  j));

     }
 }
```

As you can see these two Arrays are not equal and the code returns false. We also created a new array from an Array list that returns the numbers that are the same in the Array. We return the new Object that we have created and print it to the console as well.

And here is your output:

```
false
[Ljava.lang.Object;@7852e922
[1, 2, 4]
[Ljava.lang.Object;@4e25154f
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer but unfortunately the interface cannot be changed. This is a task for my object oriented programming class. The requirements are a bit unclear, but I am sure that the interface cannot be changed and that the class "Object_array_test" has to test out 2 Object arrays.